# My python code for MNIST dataset shows gigantic error values, what I am missing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mnist

Below you can find my code which is my first serious code for teaching myself machine learning and Python. I tried to write the code from scratch without using libraries like NumPy. For single input and output, the code works, but when it comes to real datasets (which in this case is 784 inputs to 10 outputs), it returns infinity as the error. I checked whatever I thought that might be the problem without success.

The code may be a dirty solution. I started with the code from studying Trask Github and his code for multiple input/output works, but when I modified it to use MNIST, everything becomes crazy.
Could someone take a look and help me to know what I am missing and what the problem(s) is(are)? Appreciated.

```
for i in range (x_train.shape[0]):
    x_labels[i,x_label[i]]=1
def w_sum(a,b):
    assert(len(a) == len(b))
    output = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        output += (a[i] * b[i])
    return output

def neural_network(input1, weights):
    pred = vect_mat_mul(input1,weights)
    return pred

def vect_mat_mul(vect,matrix):
    output = np.zeros(10)
    for i in range(10):

        output[i] = w_sum(vect[0],matrix[:,i])

    return output
def outer_prod(a, b):
    out = np.zeros((len(a), len(b)))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):
            out[i][j] = a[i] * b[j]
    return out

(x_train,x_label),(t_test,t_label)=ks.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],28*28)
weights=np.random.rand(784,10)
x_labels=np.zeros((x_train.shape[0],10))
alpha = 0.00001

for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    error = np.zeros(10)
    delta = np.zeros(10)
    for iter in range(50):
        x_train_to_NN = np.array([x_train[i]])
        pred = neural_network(x_train_to_NN, weights)
        for j in range(10):
            error[j] = (pred[j] - x_labels[i, j]) ** 2
            delta[j] = pred[j] - x_labels[i, j]
        weight_deltas = outer_prod(x_train[i], delta) #calculate the gradient
        for idx in range(784):
            for jdx in range(10):
                weights[idx][jdx] -= alpha * weight_deltas[idx][jdx] #update weight matrix

print('key=', i, '\n Error=', error, '\n Delta=', delta, '\n Prediction=', pred)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer and that is "[Gradient Clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem)".
The thing was when the gradient is being calculated, it is needed to be restricted (normalized) to avoid gradient explosion.

Answer (score -1):

I see a lot of mistakes here.
One of the main benefits of using NN libraries like tensorflow, pyTorch etc is that they take care of the beautiful, yet pretty mindbending, linear algebra parts for you.
For examples, all the weights of a neural network are being initialized in a special way so that they are neither greater than 1, nor much less than 1, else, the gradients do vanish or explode too quickly.
Also, it's not clear where you are computing your gradients, updating the cost function, etc. To compute the gradients you need to go to the log space and come back so you avoid again the floating point error which will lead to gradient explosion (thus the infinity error). :)
I'd suggest you get a better look in the theoretical part and then try to implement each part separately.
Cheers,

Comment: @Zultar,  weights[idx][jdx] -= alpha * weight_deltas[idx][jdx] is for updating the weights. about the gradient: weight_deltas = outer_prod(x_train[i], delta). I think it is obvious to see the parts for calculating the functions. There are a few function definitions at the beginning of the code. if you ignore them, you may find the core of the code. As I told, the code works perfectly for multiple inputs/outputs, so I assume the code itself works but when I tried to use it for MNIST, everything goes crazy. Thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: Hello!
Yes, you are right. I'm sorry I misread some parts.
But you say "  For single input and output, the code works, but when it comes to real datasets (which in this case is 784 inputs to 10 outputs),"

What I understand is that when you give as an input a 2-dimensional matrix instead of a vector then you get a numerical error. This sounds to me as exploding gradient. Do you use any activation function? On a quick check, I cannot easily see. Maybe it's a good idea to format a bit your code to increase readability.

Comment: thanks, I will go ahead and clean the code. I mean that if I have the code for restricted inputes, say 2 input and 2 ouputs, the code coverges to almost zero as the error. But I cannot get why it does not work when having the weight sized of 784x10 instead of a weight sized of 2x2. There is no activation function.

Comment: I'd suggest you add the ReLU at the output of each hidden layer. This might actually correct everything.